# Skinned Mesh Renderer - In Unity I can't change the blender modified mesh

Tags: unity, blender, mesh

I downloaded two assets from the Unity store, with the first one I built a modular character (head, torso, legs), then I took another one from the same author, to have more body "modules", but the body parts are not perfect in the joints, due to mesh intersections (ex: from head to body, the neck doesn't fit right, see the first image).

To have interchangeable body parts, I only replace the `mesh` of individual body parts (for example the head), and it works with the original FBXs (of both Assets downloaded). I can replace the `mesh` on the `Skinned Mesh Renderer` component and have a different head.

So what I did was edit the Asset Store FBX's in Blender and import them back into Unity, but the result is that of the second image.

*This mesh comes from one of the two downloaded assets FBX, and it works (even if the neck is not perfectly aligned).*
[image]

*This mesh (same name `Head Female (Bald)`) comes from an FBX that I saved from Blender. In this case, to remove any doubts, I took the original FBX, I imported it into Blender, without making any changes I exported it into FBX and imported it into Unity. This is the result:*
[image]

Note: The FBX I import from Blender, if I put it in the scene as is, it is visible with all materials.

Where am i wrong?

Thank you.

*Sorry for the first version of the question, it was confusing and I hadn't written a key part.*

Comment: Your problem might be easier to understand if you added a couple screenshots.

Comment: And have you considered that perhaps the assets are at fault, and that they are not actually designed to fit perfectly with each other?

Comment: @Philipp They seemed compatible, but the author made small changes, not that difficult to fix, and being the first free Assset, I didn't expect anything. And anyway, if I don't edit them with Blender I can use them (but the meshes don't fit well). I've updated the question with some images.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand your problem correctly. So looking at the second image, what I see is a model where the head is not just not fitting well, but actually missing completely. You then wrote something about importing the model into Blender and then again from Blender to Unity, which to me sounds like a plausible source for errors to creep in. But you didn't mention that at all in the first version of the question. It seems strange to omit such a crucial step. So I am confused if my interpretation of this question is correct.

Comment: @Philipp Sorry, maybe it's due to my bad English. In the first image the mesh is visible, and it comes from the FBX of the downloaded Asset, the original. In the second image instead, I took the original FBX, imported it into Blender, exported it as FBX and imported it into Unity. The same mesh (but from the FBX I created) however is no longer visible. The purpose is to be able to modify the original FBX in Blender (because as I said, and you can see in the first image, the neck fits badly with the torso).

Comment: So what exactly is your question? How to get that head to fit better? Or how to not make it disappear when exporting from Blender into Unity? (The second might be more of a problem for https://blender.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Philipp Forgive me, I realized that it was confusing and partial! Sometimes it happens... I hope it's clearer now.